# SFP 1000BaseT module for 1GB Uplink from Router

Tags: 10gbase

I have a Netgear 5 port 10G switch.  It has (4) 10G RJ45 ports and (1) SFP+ port.

I would like to use the SFP+ port to uplink to my router that is only 1GB.

So am I right in that I can buy a "Gigabit SFP Copper RJ45 Module 1000BASE-T Transceiver" and I should be ok?

Comment: Check to see that the module is compatible with that switch.

Comment: According to Netgear the AGM734 is compatible.  "1000BASE-T Mini-GBIC Gigabit Transceiver for Netgear AGM734"

Comment: So, you have your answer. You can post it as an answer that, yes, the switch is compatible with a 1 Gbps (not GB) copper traceiver.